# copy/paste keyframes doesn't work(?)

Tags: animation, keyframes

Well when i select a keyframe, right click it and select copy, and then paste it it doesn't paste?
I have tried searching for this on other websites (reddit,youtube etc...) but nobody seems to be having a problem like mine or everybody knows how to fix this except me.

Comment: Hello, did you select (with left click) another frame in the timeline before pasting the keyframe ? Also, if that still doesn't fix it, you can try SHIFT + D (duplicate) and move your mouse to the desired position or type the number of frames you want to move

Comment: OMG TY Soooooooo much that helped me out alot im new to blender so sorry if im stupid

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you select (with Left Click) another frame in the timeline before pasting the keyframe.

You can also duplicate the keyframe(s) with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (or Right Click > Duplicate) and move your mouse to the desired position or type the number of frames you want to move.